# proc_exit is not valid input at this position

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I was given 3 sql files to update my mysql database but when I open them in mysql workbench I am getting Syntax error that proc_exit is not valid input on this position.

The sql file starts like this

```
proc_exit:BEGIN
    DECLARE errorMessage VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE logMessage VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE logModule VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT 'DashboardLenderDaily'; 
    DECLARE lockName VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT 'dash_lendaily'; 
    DECLARE lockValue TINYINT;
```

From my understanding it starts with declaration of procedure but I am not sure what is wrong here. Should I try fix the file somehow, or maybe I am not importing it the right way - I just open the sql file in the query window and try to execute everythin

Comment: Take a look at the manual: "https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html". A BEGIN ... END block can be labeled (=Statement label). As it says that 'compound statements can appear within stored programs' you might be missing something

Comment: Try adding delimiter before the procedure like ```delimiter $$ create procedure....poc_exit....end$$ delimiter ;``` and reset back the delimiter to it's default.